# Retrieving the highest key value

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

`labels` is a dictionary of dictionaries :

I want to get the highest key value, in this example the highest key value is 4.

My piece of code to achieve that task is `labels[labels.length - 1].id` but it didn't work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `labels[Object.keys(labels).length-1]` as long as keys are contiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in Javascript, an object it is an **unordered collection of properties**, you can't find the *max* key by using just `labels[labels.length - 1].id`

You need to use `Object.keys` method and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let labels = {"1":{"id":"1","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141"},"2":{"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141"},"3":{"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"},"4":{"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"}}

console.log(Math.max(...Object.keys(labels)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys()` that sorts the object with it's `key` and then get the last key from this array. For better example I have taken a key with value `"5"` at the first place in the object:

```js
var data = {"5":{"id":"5","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141"},"2":{"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141"},"3":{"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"},"4":{"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"}};

var keys = Object.keys(data);
var highestKey = keys[keys.length - 1];
console.log('highest key value is '+ highestKey);
var higestObj = data[highestKey];
console.log(higestObj);
```

Comment: The order of Object.keys, for in and for of is not guaranteed, this may work by accident but it is not the best way to do it. Map keys to numbers and reduce to highest: `Object.keys(data).map(Number).reduce((highest,current)=>(current>highest)?current:highest)` or even better; the answer using `Math.max(...Object.keys(labels))` is in the other answer